# Add queries in runtime possible?

Tags: android

is it possible to add queries in runtime?  I know it is possible to change configurations and permissions but e.g if I want my app to interact with data of any app on my phone which is possible by having the packagename. But after API 30 I need to specify Apps I want to interact with as queries in the AndroidManifest.xml, or use the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission which I don't want to use.
Here is an Example how I imagined it:
User enters my app and wants the icon of a specific app on his phone. Then enters the package name and clicks ok and now he can see the icon of a certain app.

Comment: Hello there! Please tell us [what have you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **coughs** with code please.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to add queries in runtime?

You appear to be referring to `<queries>` elements in the manifest. If so, then no, that is not possible.

> But after API 30 I need to specify Apps I want to interact with as queries in the AndroidManifest.xml, or use the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission which I don't want to use

Or, you specify `Intent` patterns of relevance in `<queries>`.

> User enters my app and wants the icon of a specific app on his phone. Then enters the package name and clicks ok and now he can see the icon of a certain app.

First, approximately 0% of your users know package names. A more user-friendly UI would be to present the member with a list to choose from.

Second, it is unclear what you mean by "the icon of a certain app". If you mean "a *launcher* icon from a certain app", then basically you want similar capabilities to a launcher: show a list (or grid or whatever) of launcher icons for the user to choose from, after which you can do something with the chosen icon.

For that scenario, this should suffice:

```xml
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent>

  </queries>
```

You can then use `queryIntentActivities()` to find the launcher activities on the device:

```kotlin
private val LAUNCHER_INTENT =
  Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)

data class MainViewState(
  val launcherActivities: List<ResolveInfo>
)

class MainMotor(private val context: Context) : ViewModel() {
  private val _states = MutableLiveData<MainViewState>()
  val states: LiveData<MainViewState> = _states

  fun load(force: Boolean = false) {
    if (force || _states.value == null) {
      val pm = context.packageManager

      _states.value = MainViewState(
        launcherActivities = pm.queryIntentActivities(LAUNCHER_INTENT, 0)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately I found out the thing wanted to do is not possible for now

Answer (score 0):

Hmh... read a bit more about Androidmanifest.xmls and Queries and found out the App i planned to do is exactly sth Google doesnt want to have so....
But still thanks for the answers ^^

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).